# Android swipe transition

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement an Android swipe transition on an image within my layout so the user can get some feedback while they are selecting the image.

So, the user would ideally place their finger on the image, and drag it right, and have the image track it until the user has sufficiently dragged it far enough right, just like it is shown here (from the Android dropdown menu in the second item):

http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7301/8716433318_d58aaaa567.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily implemented with a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: Is there a way that you can do this in more of a stacked transition rather than a panning from side to side of two images like in ViewPager? Example: two images stacked on top of each other. Select and swipe right the image on top, to reveal the image on the bottom.

Comment: I'm guessing you need something similar to a Filmstrip? How about using Gallery view?